# Determine, whether there are elements at given point

Tags: cytoscape.js

I need to determine whether there are elements at defined point. I use inefficient method for this purpose now in my opinion: I search all existing elements, that has require coordinates on greed.

```
function is_position_empty(eles, grid_x, grid_y, sector){
    var targets = eles.filter(function(ele){
        return ele.position('grid_y') == grid_y && ele.position('grid_x') == grid_x && ele.position('sector') == sector;
    });
    return targets.empty();
}
```

But I think, that this no good solution for many elements.

I think that determines whether anything is rendered at a given point is better. But I can't find this performance on documentation.

Please, tell me, how I can determine, whether anything is rendered at a given point